# Why my tkinter frame is not on the top of the canvas and canvas can still be scrolled up?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm creating a GUI tool and while working on it, I faced an issue that I couldn't figure out why it is happening.

I have a scrollable frame inside a canvas, however that frame is not on the top side of the canvas "even though I want it on the top side" and I noticed that the canvas can still be scrolled up above the frame (frame background is green) which is I consider a wrong behavior.

It doesn't matter how many times, I checked the code and revised/edited it, I still cannot figure it out, so I decided to check here for any hints and thank you in advance.

My code is as follow

```
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import *
    
root = Tk()
root.title("Checklist Buddy")
root.config(padx=10, pady=5)
root.geometry("800x500")

top_frame = Frame(root, bg="black")
top_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

mf = Frame(root, bg="brown")
mf.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="NEWS")

canvas = Canvas(mf, bg="yellow")
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NEWS")

yscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(mf, command=canvas.yview)
yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)

bpo_frame = Frame(canvas, background="green")
win = canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=bpo_frame, height=100)


def _on_mousewheel(event):
    canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")


def onCanvasConfigure(event):
    canvas.itemconfigure(win, width=event.width)


canvas.bind('<Configure>', onCanvasConfigure, add="+")
canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", _on_mousewheel)

root.columnconfigure("all", weight=1)
root.rowconfigure("all", weight=1)

mf.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
# mf.rowconfigure("all", weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Below is a picture to show what I mean, there shall be no empty yellow space above the green window (no scroll up shall be there as the window shall be on the top side)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is the scrollregion of the canvas, which is set to a region with negative y-coordinates. If you want the point `(0,0)` to be at the top of the canvas, you need to define it. And don't change it once the canvas is reconfigured.

Also, the canvas window needs an anchor in the top left corner. Otherwise, it is centered on `(0,0)` and reaches half into the negative x and y coordinates.

If you change the lines 15-25 as follows, the behavior is as expected:

(Personally, I would also set the width of the window equal to the width of the canvas before scrolling the first time instead of binding this change to the `<Configure>`. But you may have a reason for this)

```
canvas = Canvas(mf, bg="yellow",scrollregion=(0, 0, 1000, 1000))
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NEWS")

yscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(mf, command=canvas.yview)
yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

#canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)

bpo_frame = Frame(canvas, background="green")
win = canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=bpo_frame, height=100, anchor=NW)
```